# Attach a master page to a new page created in Sharepoint

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, master-page

As you know we can create a page in sharepoint site in browser in `"Site Actions"` using `"create a new page"`. And by using Sharepoint designer as `".aspx"` and `".html"` pages.
I have created a publishing site in a site collection and created a page in it using `"site actions"`.  This page is not reflected in sharepoint designer. Should I have to publish and approve it?
Then, If I create a page using sharepoint designer, It does not have master page attached to it. How can I attach a master page to a newly created page in sharepoint designer? If it is created using `"Site Actions"` the master page is already attached to it.

Comment: Did you check for the page created by site actions under site pages library in designer?

Comment: Yeah, The pages are in "All Files/Page".

Comment: One more doubt,
 If there is any problem if I create page using "Page From Master" in master pages in navigation in Sharepoint designer or create a Webpart page or ".aspx" page in sharepoint designer  or using "site Actions"and attach a master page as suggested in this answer.
I need a page for displaying div's containing links. Which way should I create this page? which one has less limitations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your site is a publishing portal then all pages will be created in library called `pages`.

**1.** Page created from site actions not seen in designer.

Once you create your page from site actions do following to check for a page in designer

- Open your publishing site in Designer and click on `All Files` tab from left menu.
- Now from the listed menu options, you will notice there will be a `Pages` options. That's where all pages live
- Click on `Pages` to  open and find your newly created page
- If you are unable to find the page, then try to `refresh` designer and check again.

**2.** Page created from designer not attached to master page.

- Open the page (*which is created from designer*) in advanced mode
- On ribbon control, find `STYLE` tab and open it.
- You will notice, that the first option available is `Attach`
- Click on `Attach` to drop open available master pages and select your desired one.

refer below screen shot for attaching a master page.

[image]

Comment: One more doubt,
Now I am confused,  If there is any problem if I create page using "Page From Master" in master pages in navigation in Sharepoint designer or create a Webpart page or ".aspx" page in sharepoint designer  or using "site Actions"and attach a master page as suggested in this answer.
I need a page for displaying div's containing links. Which way should I create this page? which one has less limitations?

Answer (score 1):

As you are using a publishing site, you should create a webpart page in Pages library. This way the master page will be attached to it and it will also get reflected in the designer.

you can also add the below code in the page to link it with the default master page of the site

```
<%@ Page language="C#" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master"    Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage,Microsoft.SharePoint,Version=15.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" meta:webpartpageexpansion="full" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document"  %>
```

Here **MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master"** is the link to the default master page of site.

[image]

Edit page in Advance Mode:

Comment: But if I create a webpart page, when I try to edit that file in sharepoint designer, It is marked a yellow color and I can't edit the file.

Comment: Open it in "Edit in Advance Mode". right click on page and select "Edit in Advance mode".